# libphonenumber Jar File Compatible with Java JRE 1.7.0_79

Tags: java, libphonenumber

I have a project where I need to have the international numbers in the following format **CoutryCode-AreaCode-NationalNumber** before querying a database. For example, when I receive a call from France, I have to format it to be like **33-06-60684937** instead of **330660684937**.

I have come across the following thread https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber. Can someone please advise if my request would be possible with this library and how to find the required Jar file.

Comment: You can find the jar you want here : https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/libphonenumber/libphonenumber/.

Answer (score 0):

For the lib phone number there a demo site where you can test the processing of your number.
[Result of demo site](https://libphonenumber.appspot.com/phonenumberparser?number=330660684937&country=FR&geocodingLocale=fr)

I think the Country Code / National Number can be extracted.
country_code    33
national_number 660684937

From my view the Area Code can't extracted over on field.

E164 format +33660684937

Original format 330660684937

National format 06 60 68 49 37

International format    +33 6 60 68 49 37

Out-of-country format from US   011 33 6 60 68 49 37

Out-of-country format from CH   00 33 6 60 68 49 37

Maybe you can use a custom formater to get your desired result